# Shared Element Transition XML Resource between RecyclerView Items and a Simple Fragment

Tags: android, animation, fragment, android-recyclerview, shared-element-transition

--A-- When I use SharedElementTransition between two Activities I have no problem,

--B-- When I use SharedElementTransition between two Fragments I have no problem, too!

It means the standard shared element transition effect of Lollipop will be displayed and there is no problem.

--C-- but when I use it between two Fragments and there is a RecyclerView in one of the Fragments and the purpose is to transform some views in the RecyclerView Items to curresponding views in another Fragment, the standard shared element transition effect won't be displayed at all!!!

The odd thing is that the XML files are the same in --B-- and --C-- !!!

this is that XML Transition Resource:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<transitionSet xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <changeTransform />
    <changeBounds />
</transitionSet>
```

I'm going to implement something like this animation: https://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html

Can anyone help me?